# Postgres database has all columns joined but now I'm stuck on creating new entities that are wired together. Any ideas?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have a Postgres database containing Movies, Raters, and Ratings. Each Movie object and each Rater object has a OneToMany relationship with Rating. I'm using Spring Data JPA and have connected them with @JoinColumn annotations, and it all seemed to be working until I got to the actual logic that's supposed to use the information within the databases. I'm getting the following error when trying to create a new Rating object: `ERROR 2772 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.stephenalexander.projects.movierecommender.rating.Rating.movie; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value`

Here are my Rating and Movie classes:

```
@Entity(name = "Rating")
@Table(name = "rating")
public class Rating {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
    )
    @Column(name = "rating_id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "rating")
    private Double ratingValue;

    private LocalDateTime time;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "rater_id", nullable = false)
    private Rater rater;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id", nullable = false)
    private Movie movie;

    public Rating(Integer movieID, Double ratingValue) {
        this.ratingValue = ratingValue;

        this.time = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
```

```
@Entity(name = "Movie")
@Table(name = "movie")
public class Movie {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.AUTO
    )
    @Column(name = "movie_id")
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private int year;
    @Column(name = "posterurl")
    private String posterUrl;
    @Column(name = "runningtime")
    private int runningTime;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Rating.class, mappedBy = "movie")
    List<Rating> ratings;
```

Here is the service layer for Ratings:

```
@Service
public class RatingService {

    private final RatingRepository ratingRepository;

    @Autowired
    public RatingService(RatingRepository ratingRepository) {
        this.ratingRepository = ratingRepository;
    }

    public void addNewRating(Rating rating) {
        ratingRepository.save(rating);
    }
```

And the RatingRepository has the (as far as I know) standard wiring for Spring Data JPA:

```
@Repository
public interface RatingRepository extends CrudRepository<Rating, Long> {

}
```

When I create a new rating, I am trying to do so by only passing the reference to the ID of the movie, letting the database connect them. I've been calling `addNewRating(ratingObject)` from the `RatingService`. Some advice I've received is to wire things up by storing references to IDs instead of having all of the objects hold other objects within them. Here, I had to add the private Movie in order to define the relationships between the entities, and I think this conflict is where my mental block currently lies.

As it is, it appears there's nothing interpreting the ID when I make a new Rating by giving an Integer reference in the constructor. Have I misconfigured the related columns, or is there an annotation I can add to the constructor within Rating to let it know that the Integer I'm giving when I make a new Rating is pointing to the private Movie within the class? Or do I need to wire my MovieRepository into my service layers anywhere I am creating a new rating in order to get an actual Movie object to pass into the Rating constructor? Thanks for your time!

EDIT: Added some clarification to the questions I'm asking.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing more code where you actually create and save the entities. Also it will be easier to debug if you write a unit test to cover this case rather than calling it from a web request.

Comment: Don't have time today to explore unit testing, but I'll try it tomorrow. That would definitely help. Added a bit of extra logic above if it helps clarify things. Thanks!

Comment: @StephenCarroll before saving rating or movie or rater any object, you have to set all references correctly, since all these are bidirectional relationships.
Before saving Rating - rating should have reference to Movie object and Movie object should have this "Rating" object added to list "ratings" field.
That is the issue you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a few issues, primary among them was what Lucia outlined in the comments. There was no reason to have the relationships from `Rating` to `Movie` and `Rater` be bidirectional, and that was my mistake having followed some tutorials.

I removed the `Movie` and `Rater` member variables entirely from `Rating` and went back to `int` and `Long` references to their IDs. The annotations in `Movie` and `Rater` now read:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "rating")
```

I also had an issue auto-generation of IDs and not letting the database assign an ID to `Rater` or `Rating` objects before trying to save them. All of this has really helped me get my head around the relationship between the database functionality and my view in Java, so thanks for your help everyone.